# How to pass a variable defined through JSTL in JSP Page into Java bean

Tags: java, jsp, argument-passing

I have Jstl coding in JSP Page as

```
<td style="${r.p46_readback-row.p46_readback eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p46_readback-row.p46_readback)}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.## (" var="nn"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${r.p46_readback-row.p46_readback ne 0}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.p46_readback-row.p46_readback)/r.p46_readback}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${mm}" ></c:out><c:out value=")"></c:out></c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="00%)"></c:out>
</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
```

Now I need to pass variable nn into java bean as a argument to a method.How to do that.
Is it possible to pass variables set in  tag into bean class??

Comment: Can you post your java bean class here ? I don't understand why you have to do this

Comment: @TienNguyen, I have to take this value of nn to bean and compare it with another value which I retrieve from database,and if nn value exceeds that database value then red color should be displayed otherwise green . Is this possible to do in jsp only.??How

Comment: How is this jsp invoked? From a servlet? You could do it there and set an attribute indicating that the formatted value exceeds the one in the db. Use that attribute in the jsp to display your colour.

Comment: @ramp,I'm not using servlets ,just jsp and bean .

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution to help you archive this. Let me start from line 3 of your code:

```
<c:out value="${nn}"></c:out>
<%
    Number number = (Number) pageContext.getAttribute("nn");

    // create your java bean here and set the number variable to the bean
    // after that you can do whatever you want with your bean
%>
```

Comment: Through number , I can access this nn in jsp bean???I will take value from database into bean and compare thata value with nn in jsp..something like this>??

Comment: The number is exactly your nn value so you have to create a number field at the bean that you expect to set nn into. After that you can use the bean to query your database.

Comment: why you used number,Can't I use float there?

Comment: Sure you can use float there, because i don't know exactly what your data is so i put Number here, Number is parent of all data type class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html